# Powershell 5.1: how to display IP address of each node in a cluster?

Tags: powershell

`Get-ClusterNode` cmdlet outputs only `Name`, `State` and `Type` properties of each node:

```
PS C:\Users\x> Get-ClusterNode -Cluster abc_clust

Name           State Type
----           ----- ----
abc1           Up    Node
abc2           Up    Node
```

Meanwhile `Get-ClusterResource` offers only Cluster IP Address (i.e. virtual IP) among "IP Address" resource types:

```
PS C:\Users\x> Get-ClusterResource

Name               State  OwnerGroup      ResourceType
----               -----  ----------      ------------
Cluster IP Address Online Cluster Group   IP Address
Cluster Name       Online Cluster Group   Network Name
File Share Witness Online Cluster Group   File Share Witness
```

Is there any cmdlet or a combination of them that might return the physical IP addresses of each individual cluster node?

Comment: Pipe them to a `Get-Member` to see all the properties that can be gathered from them.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this cmdlet: `Get-ClusterParameter`, if you pipe the resource from `Get-ClusterResource` you can get the extended values of the piped resource.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/get-clusterparameter

Also found this for you:

https://kimconnect.com/powershell-list-all-ips-used-by-cluster/